# How to format numbers to currency as the user types in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to format a users input as a currency. I have an input field where a user would type how much they want to pay. As they type the number I would like it to start formatting as they type. So formatting wise I would like it to look like:

> $1,200.23

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-dollars-currency-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Intl` `NumberFormat` method with `currency` set to `USD`

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#currency");
const [label] = input.labels;
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"});

input.addEventListener("input", e => {
  label.textContent = formatter.format(input.value)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="currency">
<label for="currency"></label>
```

Comment: This is so close to what I am looking for. I just would love the input to update accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: @Zachary You can change `type` of `<input>` to `"text"` and use `change` event instead of `input` event with `input.value = formatter.format(input.value.replace(/[$]+/, ""))`

Comment: @Zachary Using `input` event `input.addEventListener("input", e => {
  if (!/[0-9.]+/.test(e.data)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
  input.value = formatter.format(input.value.replace(/[$]+/, ""))`